# How to set a cookie only for a domain (without subdomains)?

Tags: php, cookies

I need to set cookies for example.com, but I want static.example.com to be cookie-less.

Setting the domain parameter in setcookie() will make them available for example.com and all its subdomains, which I don't want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done, apparently.

If someone finds a way, I will change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#93641

[..]firefox will prepend a period (full-stop) to the domain value if the period is not already present. 
This is because firefox expects the domain parameter value, if present, to be a domain name and not a host name.

So using setcookie() with a domain value of www.example.com is not correct if www is a host name. 
If you want to restrict the cookie to a single host, supply the domain parameter as an empty string, for example (note the rightmost parameter):

```
setcookie("TestCookie", "SomeValue", time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

you could set the cookie explicitly for `www.example.com`, instead of for `example.com`. Remember that that `www.example.com` is also similar to a subdomain and setting a cookie in it will not affect `static.example.com` or `something_else.example.com`